# Will PS4 game discs work on PS5 Console?

Tags: ps4, backwards-compatibility, ps5

I recently bought a PS5, after loooooooong wait. So, the first few games that I plan are  - Bloodborne and Demon Souls. The only discs for PS4 available on Amazon India are that from PS4.

So, will those discs work?
P.S - Although, I mentioned only Bloodborne, I want a general thing about running PS4 discs on PS5

Comment: For completion it should be mentioned that you can play PS4 games with the old PS4 controllers, but need PS5 controllers for PS5 games (this can come  in handy if you want to play e.g. minecraft with 4 persons and still have two old PS4 controllers )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Playstation 4 discs should work with a Playstation 5.

There is an [official help page](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/support/games/ps5-backward-compatibility-games/) on the subject:

> The overwhelming majority of the 4,000+ PS4 games are playable on PS5 consoles.

> **Playing PS4 game discs on a PS5 console with a disc drive**
>
> 1. Insert the PS4 game disc. You may need to download an update.
> 2. Select the game hub from your Games home.
> 3. You will need to keep the disc inserted each time to play the game.
>
> PS4 game discs can’t be used with the PlayStation®5 Digital Edition.

Comment: The best feature is that, if the game has also a PS5 version, you can download the upgraded version. Some games let you do this for free.

Comment: @pinckerman Can you list out those games, or share a link? Sorry, this is my first console. The last one that I had, was a Nintendo 3DS, bought by my father

Comment: @Asish a good amount are listed here: https://www.pushsquare.com/guides/ps4-to-ps5-all-games-with-confirmed-free-upgrades

Answer (score 6):

To add to Timmy Jim's answer: there are only 6 PS4 games that just straight up do not work on PS5:

- Afro Samurai 2: Revenge of Kuma Volume One
- Hitman Go: Definitive Edition
- Just Deal With It!
- Robinson: The Journey
- Shadwen
- We Sing

There are also around 130 games that will launch and be playable, with the caveat that there might be some graphical glitches and bugs. I'm not going to copy them all here because SE doesn't have an easy way to turn them into a list, but you can find the list [here](https://www.pushsquare.com/guides/ps5-backwards-compatibility-can-you-play-ps4-games-on-playstation-5#all-ps4-games-that-may-exhibit-errors-on-ps5).

Comment: Thanks for the details. @Nzall